# Save txt file in DB and calculate the percentage of used tCodes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a text file

first.txt

```
tCodeA;tCodeB;tCodeC
tCodeB;tCodeC
tCodeD;tCodeA
tCodeB
```

Every line is a Package
every package includes one or more tCodes
tCodes are separated with semicolon

1. how can I store text data in db (line by line) as list or array?
2. app must Get the tCode or tCodes from us and tell the percentage of the tCode used among lines

```
        public void DbBuilder(string input)
        {
                StreamReader sr = new("C:\\first.txt");
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(line);
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sr.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Database stores data as string, won't store list type directly. For list type, it will use multiple table with primary keys to establish a relationship.
 For example. Transfer your txt into database may need 2 tables to achieve. "Packages" table and "tCodes" table.
[image]
[image]
As you can see packageID 1 appears 3 times in the "tCodes" table. That represent package1 contains the 3 corresponding CodeNames.

Following is a quick guide for this solution.
1.install sqlite https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite/ 
2.install sqlite browser https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/ 
3.create asp.net core console app with .net6 
4.install nugetpackage 
Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore (6.xx)
Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Tools (6.xx)
Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Design (6.xx)
Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Sqlite (6.xx)
5.Change the program.cs to the following code.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


internal class Program
{
    public class tCode
    {
        [Key]
        public int CodeId { get; set; }
        public string CodeName { get; set; }

        public int PackageID { get; set; }
        public Package Package { get; set; }  
    }

    public class Package
    {     
        public int PackageID { get; set; }
        public List<tCode> package { get; set; }
    }
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=C://first.db3");
        }

        public DbSet<Package> Packages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<tCode> tCodes { get; set; }


    }



    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var _context = serviceProvider.GetService<DatabaseContext>();   //inject and ready the database


        StreamReader sr = new("C:\\first.txt");
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);

            var currentList = line.Split(";").ToList(); //convert line to a list value

            Package package = new Package();
            _context.Packages.Add(package);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();   //Add a new package ID to "Package" table

            foreach (var codes in currentList)
            {
                tCode tCode = new tCode() { CodeName = codes, PackageID = package.PackageID };
                _context.tCodes.Add(tCode);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();      //add the code name and packageID to "tCodes" table 1 by 1.
            }

            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        sr.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
        
    }
}
```

6.create an empty database using efcore. In the nugetpackage console run `add-migration initial` and then `update-database`.
7. Run this app. It will read the txt and put the value into database like we mentioned on the top.